# When to use the "enableSourcing" option while trying to save a record in NetSuite?

Tags: javascript, database, netsuite, suitescript2.0

After user clicked the "Save" button in PO on NetSuite, the script will update some values from PO to SO.

I tried to enable and disable the option "enableSourcing" for record.save. But the saving duration is very small, maybe just differ in 1 or 2 seconds.

The code is as follows:

```
 try {
     so_record.save({
         enableSourcing: true
     });
 } catch (error) {
     log.debug('error.message', error.message);
 }
```

If the option is not necessary in my case, I want to remove the option for better maintenance.

But I am not sure the usage of "enableSourcing", does anybody know what usage the option is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Indicates whether to enable sourcing during the record update. Defaults to true.

Sourcing is when you load list field information, for example, the list of locations for the subsidiary selected. If you're not changing any sourceable lists, then might as well turn it off.

Comment: do you mean that once user select an option of the list of the locations for the subsidiary, the other fields will show the related information for the option?

Comment: Yeah, sort of. It's like a simulation of what would happen in the UI if you select customer => subsidiary= > location => etc. Would apply the defaulting values once the preceding list is selected.